# Ionic 2 and Angular - compatible versions (has no exported member)

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2

How can I know which angular version is supported for each Ionic version? I'm constantly getting errors  "has no exported member", for example :

> Module `".../node_modules/@angular/core/index"` has no exported member
>   `InjectionToken`.
>
> Module `".../node_modules/@angular/core/index"` has no exported
>   member `ComponentResolver`.

then I google it and usually, the forums suggest to update the versions. I do that but then I get another incompatible version error.

Here is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.2.1",
"@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
"@angular/core": "2.2.1",
"@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
"@angular/http": "2.2.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",

"@ionic-native/core": "3.1.0-rc.6",
"@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.5.3",
"@ionic-native/google-maps": "^4.5.3",
"@ionic-native/network": "^4.5.3",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.2",
"@ionic-native/sqlite": "^4.5.3",
"@ionic-native/sqlite-porter": "^4.5.3",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.2",
"@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",

"angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
"firebase": "^3.2.1",
"ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.11",
"ionic-native": "2.4.1",
"ionic-plugin-keyboard": "~2.2.1",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"moment": "^2.20.1",
"ng2-cordova-oauth": "0.0.6",
"rxjs": "5.5.2",
"statex": "^1.1.3",
"sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
"typescript": "^2.7.2",
"uk.co.workingedge.cordova.plugin.sqliteporter": "^1.0.2",
"zone.js": "0.8.18"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.0",
  "typescript": "2.6.0-rc"
},
```

My project was working fine, and I started to get these kinds of errors since I added a firebase dependency.

Can someone help me, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To update the ionic did you use this command or any other?

npm update -g ionic

In the ionic forum there is a how to upgrade procedure. See if it will solve these problems that are occurring with you. I hope it helps.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/upgrading-existing-ionic-project-to-latest-version/95224/3

Comment: Well, I don't really want to upgrade the ionic version, because I'll probably get more conflict errors. I guess if I found the correct version of each lib, which are compatibles with the ionic version, would be better.